# Issue with Authorize attribute and cache

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, authorization

I've an issue on ASP.NET MVC.
I've created a custom AuthorizeAttribute in order to get Roles for each actions and each controllers from a database.

Here is the code :

```
public class CustomAuthAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private string[] _roles;
    private Db_Entities db = new Db_Entities();
    private String controller;
    private String action;

    public CustomAuthAttribute(String controller, String action)
    {
        this.controller = controller;
        this.action = action;           
    }


    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");
        }

        Actions myAction = db.Actions.Where(a => a.Libelle.Equals(this.action)).Single(a => a.Controller.Equals(this.controller));
        List<String> myGroupeList = new List<String>();
        foreach (Groupes g in myAction.Groupes)
        {
            myGroupeList.Add(g.Groupe);
        }
        this._roles = myGroupeList.ToArray<string>();

        IPrincipal user = httpContext.User;
        if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return false;
        }

        bool isAuthorized = false;

        RoleProviderAD rp = new RoleProviderAD();
        string[] DbRoles = rp.GetRolesForUser(httpContext.User.Identity.Name);
        foreach (string str in DbRoles)
        {
            if (this._roles.Contains(str))
            {
                isAuthorized = true;
            }
        }
        return isAuthorized;
    }

}
```

When 'Index' action from 'Home' controller is called, AuthorizeCore is called too and datas concerning user rights are caught from database.
However if i change data from database, when I call this page again, old datas are caught in spite of the code seems have to be run again.

I tried to use ActionFilterAttribute but due to the order, it's not working. I also tried to add some rules on our IIS server. Everything has failed.
If someone could help me, that will be great !

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any ajax calls.Try to include this code before  ajax call

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

Comment: There is no Ajax call for this action

Comment: How you call your method?

Comment: In this case, it's a simple link : Html.ActionLink("Accueil", "Index", "Home")